# How can I specify a branch when creating a file on github via the content API?

Tags: ruby, github, github-api, rest-client

I am trying to create a file in a certain branch on github via the API, but don't find a way to set the branch successfully for either getting or creating the file. Here is my method:

```
   def self.save_file_to_github access_token, github_user, github_repo, path, content, branch

     sha = nil
     url = "https://api.github.com/repos/#{github_user}/#{github_repo}/contents/#{path}"
     RestClient.get(url,{ params:{access_token:access_token,branch:branch},accept:'json'}){ |response, request, result| 
         if response.code==200 
           sha=JSON.parse(response)['sha']
         end
     }

     RestClient.put(url, { message: "my message", content: Base64.strict_encode64(content), sha: sha }.to_json,{ params:{access_token:access_token},accept:'json'}){ |response, request, result| 
        puts response.code
        puts response
     }

   end
```

It first checks if the file is there, gets the sha1 key. Then its put the new file. This all works fine, I just can't find a way to specify the branch when getting the file and putting it again. How can I specify the branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action you're using in the [Repo API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/) to [retrieve](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) the file if it's there takes a parameter `ref` which defaults to the `master` branch. Replace this with the branch you need.

For [creating](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file) the file, the parameter in the API is called `branch` and again defaults to `master`. Set this to your required branch and you should be good to go. Something like this:

```
def self.save_file_to_github access_token, github_user, github_repo, path, content, branch

  sha = nil
  url = "https://api.github.com/repos/#{github_user}/#{github_repo}/contents/#{path}"
  RestClient.get(url,{ params:{access_token:access_token, ref: branch},accept:'json'}){ |response, request, result| 
    if response.code==200 
      sha=JSON.parse(response)['sha']
    end
  }

  RestClient.put(url, { message: "my message", content: Base64.strict_encode64(content), branch: branch, sha: sha }.to_json,{ params:{access_token:access_token},accept:'json'}){ |response, request, result| 
    puts response.code
    puts response
  }

end
```

Comment: This works!! I am surprised to see that its used one time in the http-headers and the other time in the payload.